# WPF windows runtime event

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In Wpf Window/winForms is there an event that is constantly being called? Such as WindowReady()

I want to have the capability of hiding my windows but have a check for a value change on a non related task that is unbindable. My current procedure is running a timer that is calling an event but this seems like hack.

Open to any suggestions welcome, thanks.

Comment: Event as you might already know, are called when something occurs or tigger event, if you just want to do a thing on "change of variable" then using MVVM like model will help you track change in variable value and fire an event, Otherwise timer thing is not bad, or attaching a Event with Variable property's set method is good idea too.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean 'task that is unbindable'? Are you trying to poll an external service or database? Get notified when a background task modifies a value or raises an event? Using a timer for polling is the natural solution, using an `Idle` event is the hack

Comment: I trying to keep track of the mouse and its location relative to what wapplication it has focus on. My problem is that I want to modify the main thread of the program that is tracking this and when we use timers it runs this event in a background thread so it is unable to access the main thread variable (aka "this.val").

Answer (score 0):

As far as an event that is constantly called, it depends on what is happening in your environment. If there is constant UI activity, then the Activated event is nearly always firing. This can be very handy. However if you are talking something like a watchdog, your timer is pretty much the basic concept right there.

Answer (score 0):

You can read something about Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(), but i suppose timers is more situable.